# How to avoid infinite loop in save_post callback

Tags: save-post, wp-update-post

I have been using this site alot for solving my problems, but this time I did not succeed in finding and answer for my problem.

I get and infinite loop when using `wp_update_post` inside a function that is called on `save_post`. I know that this is a common issue, but I can't figure out how to avoid it.

I want to save the order of my posts (which is of the post-type 'section'). So I have made a custom meta box which contain some sortable html-elements. In each element there is an hidden input tag with name='sectionorder[]'. So when I click the standard WordPress 'Update' buttom, an array containing all the ID's of the posts (in order) are send via POST. So here is the code where I retrieve the array, and wants to save the order:

```
    // Update section sort order
$sectionorder = $_POST['sectionorder'];
if (isset($sectionorder)) { // Avoid error if there is no sections added yet
    foreach( $sectionorder as $no => $sectionID ) {
        $post_update = array();
        $post_update['ID'] = $sectionID;
        $post_update['menu_order'] = $no;
        wp_update_post( $post_update );
    }
}
```

But the problem is that it starts an infinite loop. How do I avoid that? Maybe I can do it in a completely different way?

Appriciate your help!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can remove the callback from the `save_post` hook, update the post and then re-add the call back to the hook. The [Codex gives an example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops).

```
add_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post');

function wpse51363_save_post($post_id) {

    //Check it's not an auto save routine
     if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
          return;

    //Perform permission checks! For example:
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
          return;

    //Check your nonce!

    //If calling wp_update_post, unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post');

    // call wp_update_post update, which calls save_post again. E.g:
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'private'));

    // re-hook this function
    add_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post');
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the quick reply. Works like a charm! Don't know why I didn't see that code example myself..

Comment: @Stephen, I use `update_post_meta` in a function hooked to `save_post` should I also unhook and rehook after `update_post_meta`?

Comment: No, `update_post_meta` won't (generally) cause `save_post` to be triggered.

Comment: After wasting an hour found this and this also saved more hours, thank you.

Comment: works for me, in the year 2020

Answer (score 19):

I haven't quite got the reputation to comment so I'm adding an answer even though Stephen's is excellent and correct. It just doesn't handle instances when you want to set the priority of the action.

If you set the priority when adding the action but don't specify priority when you remove it you will still get an infinite loop.

```
add_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post', 25 );
```

// The WRONG way to handle this - leads to infinite loop

```
remove_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post');
wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'private'));
add_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post');
```

// The RIGHT way to handle this - executes only once

```
remove_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post', 25 );
wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'private'));
add_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post', 25 );
```

Comment: Wow thanks!  I was going nuts trying to figure out why I was still getting the infinite loop, even when adding `remove_action/add_action`.

Comment: [WordPress Codex :: Plugin API/Action Reference/save post :: Avoiding infinite loops](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops) They demonstrate this. If you look at [WordPress Codex :: Function Reference/remove action :: Usage](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action#Usage) "The priority of the function (as defined when the function was originally hooked)." If not specified, it uses the default priority (10). A/K/A - You must specify the SAME priority as when the action was added, in order to ACTUALLY remove the action.

Comment: This is the response I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather quick and dirty trick but one way is to create a global variable like `$my_plugin_name_saving` and just set it to true before calling `wp_update_post` and return if the variable is already set.

```php
<?php
/* Plugin Name: My plugin name */

$my_plugin_name_saving = false;

function cc_publish_wpse_263985( $postid ) {
    global my_plugin_name_saving;

    if ( ! empty( $my_plugin_name_saving ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $my_plugin_name_saving = true;
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $postid, 'post_status' => 'private'));

}

add_action('save_post', 'cc_publish_wpse_263985');
```