# Wp_update_post: Infinite loop even with remove_action solution, OOP

Tags: hooks, errors, save-post, oop, wp-update-post

I have a quite complex PHP class, reponsible for creating and printing meta_boxes, generating and saving meta fields, ...

Each meta_box (object of class) has its own save function, that updates meta data of post (fields for them are instances of another class) as well as its `post_excerpt` and `post_content`. Yep, it's probably a little complicated, but as I'm only starting with OOP, I'm pretty happy with it so far.

**TL;DR, THE PROBLEM**: With `wp_update_post()` called on `save_post` hook, I get an infinite loop. This issue is documented on WP codex as well as mentioned here on WPSE: [How to avoid infinite loop in save_post callback](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51363/how-to-avoid-infinite-loop-in-save-post-callback).

> If you are calling a function such as wp_update_post that includes the save_post hook, 
>   your hooked function will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function 
>   before calling the function you need, then re-hook it afterward.
>
> > Source: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

This is a very simplified version of a code I am using:

```
class MetaBox {

    public function __construct() {
        // a lot of stuff, hooks and other function initiations
        add_action('save_post',array($this,'save_box'), 20);
    }

    // more stuff

    function save_box() {
        // verify nonces, bail out on autosave, ajax, cron, ...

        switch ($this->id) {
            case 'editor':
            case 'postexcerpt':

                // remove action
                remove_action('save_post', array($this,'save_box'));
                // bail out on post_revision
                if (!wp_is_post_revision($post_id) ){

                    $post = array(
                        // post id
                        'id'    => $post_id,
                        // tosave: either post_content or post_excerpt
                        // value: pulled from static associative multi-array inside MetaBox
                        $tosave => self::$meta[$this->id][$this->id]
                    );
                    wp_update_post($post);          
                }

                // add action back  
                add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_box'));

            break;
            default:
                // some saving functionality for meta values, that WORKS just fine
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an infinite loop with PHP error notice: `Undefined index: ID in XXX/web/wp-includes/post.php on line 2987`

Am I removing/adding save hook wrong? Does it have something in common with using the save function non-statically?

I am of course happy to provide the rest of the relevant code, if there's no apparent problem with this structure.

## EDIT

The infinite loop problem is gone - as @TheDeadMedic mentioned, problem lied at not matching priority.

> To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority arguments must match when the 
>   hook was added. This goes for both filters and actions. No warning will be given on 
>   removal failure.
>
> Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

## EDIT 2

As PHP is a case sensitive language, `Undefined index ID` notice problem lied in my $post array (parameter of `wp_update_meta`). The ID key must be specified uppercase.

```
$post = array(
    'ID' => $post_id    // ID must be uppercase
)
```

/////

As my question turned out to be very localized, feel free to delete it. And thanks again for helping me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the following: `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_filters'][ current_filter() ] );` right _before_ and right _after_ your call to `remove_action()`. Then search this site for `remove_action()` explanations. :)

Comment: @kaiser: Thanks for letting me know! However the `var_dump` echoes NULL and few errors:
- `Undefined index: wp_filters`
- `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`
Should this be happening? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, it's `wp_filter` without the `s` at the end.

Comment: @kaiser: Tried that, as I still have a lot to learn about Wordpress hooks and filters. Although, as the infinite loop problem is gone, is the `Undefined index: ID [...] /wp-includes/post.php on line 2987` related to hooks/filters as well? Should I be digging there?

Comment: Look at the `XDebug` output/backtrace. The error occurs somewhere where you're trying to access that array keys value - which apparently isn't set. Could mean no result, etc. Could imagine that it's from your `self::$meta[]` call. Anyway, you'll have to get the basics of `empty/isset/etc` to grasp what this is about (see php.net) and have `XDebug` or similar in your local dev stack to backtrace that.

Comment: Actually the answer is much simpler. Check the edit. Thanks again for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to match the `$priority` you used to hook the action:

```
remove_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_box' ), 20 /* Same as add_action call */ );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Make sure you take the `$post_id` argument in your `save_box` method too:

```
function save_box( $post_id ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what was causing the problem. Great eye there!