# wp_update_post breaks my function

Tags: functions, actions, wp-update-post

Good evening!

I'm trying to adjust the post title + some ACF fields after a user have submitted a custom post type ('booking').

The function I've created *almost* works!
The only problem is that wp_update_post() breaks it...

Adding wp_update_post() to the function will

1. Reset the fields stored by ACF
2. Remove the chosen category
3. Obstruct the redirect to the new post, resulting in "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded"

What it *does* though is producing the correct post title! :)

I haven't really managed to understand the logic of action / filter / hooks in Wordpress yet, and therefore would appreciate some help.

Here's the code:

```
function booking_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) !== 'booking' ) { return; }

// Update ACF fields
$object_id = get_the_ID();
$owner_id  = get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $post->post_author );
update_field( 'object', $object_id, $post_id );
update_field( 'owner', $owner_id, $post_id );

// Create post title
$first_name = wp_get_current_user()->user_firstname;
$new_title = get_the_title() . ' to ' . $first_name;
$post_data = array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $new_title,);

wp_update_post( $post_data );

}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'booking_meta', 99, 3 );
```

I have already tried this without knowing why:

```
remove_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'booking_meta' );
wp_update_post( $post_data );
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'booking_meta' );
```

That way my first problem is solved but the others persists. It also makes some required datepicker fields in the form turn blank in the resulting post.

Comment: The `wp_update_post` calls the `wp_insert_post` action, which means your code gets stuck in an endless loop. You need to use `remove_action()` to remove `booking_meta` from the hook before you call `wp_update_post()`

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie! I had tried that already actually, without knowing why... Added that info + result in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to Jacobs comments + [this similar thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135197/wp-update-post-infinite-loop-even-with-remove-action-solution-oop?rq=1):

I had to use `remove_action()` WITH matching priority, like this:

```
function booking_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) !== 'booking' ) { return; }

// Update ACF fields
$object_id = get_the_ID();
$owner_id  = get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $post->post_author );
update_field( 'object', $object_id, $post_id );
update_field( 'owner', $owner_id, $post_id );

// Create post title
$first_name = wp_get_current_user()->user_firstname;
$new_title = get_the_title() . ' to ' . $first_name;
$post_data = array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $new_title,);

remove_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'booking_meta', 99, 3 );
wp_update_post( $post_data );

}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'booking_meta', 99, 3 );
```