# Change author, disable comments, enable trackbacks for all items in library

Tags: comments, author, library

Change author, disable comments, enable trackbacks for all items in library
with 1 click not each one of them separately?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run SQL query to do this. Put this code into your `functions.php` once, run your website and then delete it.

```
global $wpdb;
$author = 1;
$comment_status = 'closed';
$ping_status = 'open';

$query = sprintf(
    'UPDATE %sposts SET `author` = %d, `comment_status` = %s, `ping_status` = %s',
    $wpdb->prefix,
    $author,
    $comment_status,
    $ping_status
);

$wpdb->query($query);
```

Or run it directly from database (for example from phpMyAdmin):

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `author` = 1, `comment_status` = 'closed', `ping_status` = 'open'
```

Of course you have to change author id to your author id and `wp_posts` to table name with your table prefix

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom plugin, use the core functions to change the status of comments, trackbacks. 
Use the follow code examples, add this to a custom plugin, a small class and activate it as  plugin. 
The class use two filter hooks to close comments and trackbacks, the second one is deactivated, but inside the source for better understanding or other requirements.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'FbCloseComments', 'get_object' ) );
class FbCloseComments {

    /**
     * Class object.
     *
     * @var null
     */
    static private $classobj;

    /**
     * Handler for the action 'init'. Instantiates this class.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return null|Remove_Comments_Absolute $classobj object
     */
    public static function get_object() {

        if ( NULL === self::$classobj ) {
            self::$classobj = new self;
        }
        return self::$classobj;
    }

    public function __construct() {

        add_filter( 'comments_open', array( $this, 'close_comments' ), 20, 2 );
        //add_filter( 'pings_open', array( $this, 'close_comments' ), 20, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Close comments, if open.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param string|boolean $open
     * @param string|integer $post_id
     *
     * @return bool|string $open
     */
    public function close_comments( $open, $post_id ) {

        // If not open, than back.
        if ( ! $open ) {
            return $open;
        }

        $post = get_post( $post_id );

        // For all post types.
        if ( $post->post_type ) {
            return FALSE;
        } // 'closed' don`t work; @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference#Discussion

        return $open;
    }
 }
```

The change of the author should you do via the `save_post` hook. You find a answer, example in this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51364/170).