# Editing post and page responding 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: server, server-load

I am trying to edit any page or post.

While editing, it takes some time and returns 503 Service Unavailable message on web.

`Hardaware Configuration
Processor :  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
Memory : 7953MiB
width: 64 bits`

Screenshot : 
[image]

Comment: Did you enabled `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` ? Have a look at `/wp-content/debug.log` first.

Comment: Yes. In debug I dont see any error . I see some Notices

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts might be stuck in infinite loop, not producing a fatal error but causing the server to timeout the request after some time. Try installing [`xdebug`](https://xdebug.org/) for your OS/distribution (`php-xdebug` in recent Ubuntu versions)  which will enforce a `xdebug.max_nesting_level` directive that should log an actual error and a call stack to help you identify the problem.

Comment: Do you think this error is because of inifine loop or some code part. Or is this something related to server down?

Comment: More likely an inifine loop caused by bad action/filter hook but so much anyone could tell without a proper debug.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the problem, please follow these steps:

1. Backup.
2. Enable debug mode by adding the following code in your `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

3. Try to replicate the issue and check `wp-content/debug.log` file to see if there is any PHP error.
4. Change your active theme to a default WordPress theme and see if the issue is happening again or not.
5. Try to disable all plugins and activate them one by one and replicate issue to find which plugin is causing issue.

In your case, you may ask help from your service provider to find which file or code is causing that issue.

Note: These type of issues could happen because of mistakes in codes. E.G, if you are using `save_post` hook, make sure it is not going to be infinite.

[How to avoid infinite loop in save_post callback](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51364/48376)